# Hide n:th td element of every tr using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table Id="modules-mgr">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
<td>lorem ispium blok</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to hide last `td` from every `tr`.
there is not any class for the `td` and `tr`, so we need to select them using `.eq`.
And also want a else if function, like resize event. if windows resize to 200 then hide last `td`, if window resize to 100 hide last two `td`.
here what i have done so far, but dint worked;

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
var width=jQuery(window).width();
    if(width < 870) {
        jQuery('table#modules-mgr tr td').eq(10).hide()

    }
    /*elseif(width < 570) {

    }
    else {

    }*/
});
```

Comment: CSS: `#modules-mgr tr td:nth-child(number_of_child<integer>) {display:none;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS only:

```
@media all and (max-width: 200px) {
    #modules-mgr td:last-child {display:none]
}
@media all and (max-width: 100px) {
    #modules-mgr td:nth-last-child(-n+2) {display:none]
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to respond to the resizing part of your question.

Comment: oh my god I forgot to use this code. thanks. Actually I am making a responsive template and stucked in a table

Answer (score 1):

Well if you actually want nth-child like it says in the title,

```
jQuery('#modules-mgr td:nth-child(10)').hide();
```

should do it the same as it would in straight css for those browsers which aren't stuck in the dark ages:

```
#modules-mgr td:nth-child(10) {
    display: none;
}
```

(If you just want the last element, see the other answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the last you can use the `last()` selector:

```
// for last
$('#modules-mgr tr td').last().hide();
// for n-th element - 0-index based
$('#modules-mgr tr td').eq(n - 1).hide();
```

Alternative:

```
// for last
$('#modules-mgr tr td:last').hide();
// for n-th element - 0-index based
$('#modules-mgr tr td:eq(n - 1)').hide();
```

Comment: how to select 9th or 10th `td` (they are not last or first)

Comment: Your code also work well, but I marked Kolink's  replay as answer to my question. Cause we prefer css then javascript. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('table#modules-mgr tr td').last().hide();
```